# Creating a dictionary from a .txt file using Python

Tags: python, dictionary

If you are given a `.txt file` which contains these contents:

```
James Doe 2/16/96 IT210 A BUS222 B PHY100 C
John Gates 4/17/95 IT101 C MATH112 B CHEM123 A
Butch Thomas 1/28/95 CS100 C MATH115 C CHEM123 B
```

How can you get it so it takes the class names and grades and puts them into an empty dictionary while ignoring the rest? I have code set up to read the `.txt file` but got stuck. Any suggestions?

This is my code for opening the file:

```
def readFile():
    new_dict = {}
    myFile = open('Students.txt', 'r')
    for line in myFile:
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the Dictionary would look like in this case?

Comment: And what are the class names and grades in that file?

Comment: Dict = {'IT210': 'A', 'BUS222': 'B', 'PHY100': 'C'}

Comment: something like that for the first line

Comment: Are the two spaces between the date and the first course intentional?

Comment: No, I fixed it. There was meant to be just one space.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making different variables for each student, why not use a list of dictionaries?

See the code below :

```
>>> dictList = []
>>> with open('Students.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            elements = line.rstrip().split(" ")[3:]
            dictList.append(dict(zip(elements[::2], elements[1::2])))       
>>> dictList
[{'IT210': 'A', 'PHY100': 'C', 'BUS222': 'B'}, {'IT101': 'C', 'MATH112': 'B', 'CHEM123': 'A'}, {'CS100': 'C', 'CHEM123': 'B', 'MATH115': 'C'}]
```

If you're looking to maintain the order as given in the txt file in the dictionary, then look into an `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 1):

Anser:

```
def readFile():
    new_dict = {}
    myFile = open('Students.txt', 'r')
    for line in myFile:
        line2=line.split()
        class1=line2[3]
        gra=line2[4]
        new_dict[class1]=gra
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li = []
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline().split()
    while line:
        dict = {}
        dict[line[-6]] = line[-5]
        dict[line[-4]] = line[-3]
        dict[line[-2]] = line[-1]
        li.append(dict)
        line = f.readline().split()

li = [{'IT210': 'A', 'PHY100': 'C', 'BUS222': 'B'}, {'IT101': 'C', 'MATH112': 'B', 'CHEM123': 'A'}, {'CS100': 'C', 'CHEM123': 'B', 'MATH115': 'C'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code does what you want.

```
import re

student = 'James Doe 2/16/96  IT210 A BUS222 B PHY100 C'
pattern = '([0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2})'
end = re.search(pattern, student).end()
found = student[end+2:]
x = found.split(' ')
numberOfEntries = len(x) / 2
i = 0
Dict = {}

while i < numberOfEntries:
    Dict[x[i]] = x[i+1]
    i = i + 1

print Dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dic={}
for line in myFile:
   info=line.split(' ')
   firstname=info[0]
   lastname=info[1]
   firstClass=info[3]
   firstgrade=info[4]
   secondClass=info[5]
   secondgrade=info[6]
   thirdClass=info[7]
   thirdGrade=info[8]
   gradeInfo={firstClass:firstgrade,secondClass:secondgrade,thirdClass:thirdgrade}
   name='%s %s' %(firstname,lastname)
   dic+={name,gradeInfo}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
student_dict = {}
for line in open('input','r'):
    line2=line.split()
    name = ' '.join(line2[0:2])
    grades = line2[3:]
    grades_dict = {grades[i]:grades[i+1] for i in xrange(0,len(grades),2)}
    student_dict[name]=grades_dict
```

gives:

```
>>> student_dict
{'James Doe': {'IT210': 'A', 'PHY100': 'C', 'BUS222': 'B'}, 'Butch Thomas': {'CS100': 'C', 'CHEM123': 'B', 'MATH115': 'C'}, 'John Gates': {'IT101': 'C', 'MATH112': 'B', 'CHEM123': 'A'}}
```